# how to highlight the mouse pointer position using c#

Tags: c#, .net

I need a simple mouse pointer highlighter in the form of a circle centered at the mouse pointer. Using Invalidate() in the below code causes rear circles along the path as flickers. They are hardly noticeable. Moreover, it doesn't draw the circle at the moment i rest the mouse.

What event should I consider to draw the circle at the position the mouse pointer is rested (tried other mouse events as well)?

Is there a way to refresh the drawing without using invalidate()?

```
 private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        SolidBrush myBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Yellow);
        Graphics gg = this.CreateGraphics();
        Point p = new Point();
        p = e.Location;
        int radius = 10;
        float x = p.X - radius;
        float y = p.Y - radius;
        float width = 5 * radius;
        float height = 5 * radius;
        gg.FillEllipse(myBrush, x, y, width, height);
        gg.dispose();
        Invalidate();

    }
```

Comment: Wrt Flicker: Have you turned on DoubleBuffering for the Form? - The normal way is to call store the mouse position in the MoveMove and then call Invalidate. The drawing should be done in the Paint evnet using its e.Graphics object.

Comment: No, I have no knowledge of it.

Comment: Well, it is a Property. Look at the Property Tab!

Comment: I have enabled DoubleBuffering to true. It Works better. But the highlighting does not work once the mouse pointer is rested. What event should I consider for it?

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer! Do you do any other painting on the Form? Only things drawn in or from the `Paint` event will persist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First turn on `DoubleBuffered = true;`

Then this should do:

```
private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Invalidate();
}

private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    float radius = 10f;
    Point pt = PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
    e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Yellow, pt.X - radius, 
                           pt.Y - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);

}
```

Since you are trying to highlight a spot on the background you may want to use a semi-transparent Color like this:

```
 using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(160, Color.Yellow)))
     e.Graphics.FillEllipse(brush, pt.X - radius, pt.Y - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);
```

You may want to play with other values for alpha than 160.